# VMware Host-Only without Host?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, malware

The question may seem confusing. I am setting up a malware lab, and would like to create a virtual private network basically between 3 VMs (so I can use tools like inetsim). I am using VMware Workstation 10, and Host-only achieves this goal; however, I don't want my host actually involved in the private network for security reasons.

Comment: Why not run ESXi instead of Workstation?

Comment: I use Workstation because I only have access to my one laptop at the moment, and need it for more than just this lab set up. Also, it is what I already have running.